# sqlalchemy: compare datetime field with string?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I have a string contains date like `'2014-09-28'` and want to search through model like following:

```
Log.query.filter(Log.created_at >= from_date)
```

For a record which has `datetime.datetime(2014, 9, 28, 5, 56, 47)` it return nothing!

I searched a lot about that but nothing work for me in the situation. Any idea why is that happening?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please show your code, including definition of `Log` and contents of `from_date`?

Comment: @JustinBarber, I think it should be "a string" rather than "`s` string"...

Comment: @Yoel That would make more sense.

Comment: Thank you guys for answers. i fixed the problem. SQLAlchemy could not compare string with datetime field, so i changed string to date format: `datetime.strptime(str, "%Y-%m-%d")`. it worked like a charm. Thanks again.